# How to reuse context pop up menus from existing view in Eclipse plugin to a newly created view?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I have created a new view for an Eclipse plugin and I want to reuse the basic pop up menus like Run As ,Open , Copy , Delete which are present in other views like package explorer. Is it possible to do that.

I am aware of menu contributions but that is something to add a new menu item to a existing list. How can I reuse the existing menus from other views?
[image]

This is how view is making the menus :

```
private void hookContextMenu() {
        MenuManager menuMgr = new MenuManager("#PopupMenu");
        menuMgr.setRemoveAllWhenShown(true);
        menuMgr.addMenuListener(new IMenuListener() {
            public void menuAboutToShow(IMenuManager manager) {
                SuitAExplorer.this.fillContextMenu(manager);
            }
        });
        Menu menu = menuMgr.createContextMenu(viewer.getControl());
        viewer.getControl().setMenu(menu);
        getSite().registerContextMenu(menuMgr, viewer);
    }

private void fillContextMenu(IMenuManager manager) {
        manager.add(action1);
        manager.add(action2);
        manager.add(new Separator());
        drillDownAdapter.addNavigationActions(manager);
        // Other plug-ins can contribute there actions here
        manager.add(new Separator(IWorkbenchActionConstants.MB_ADDITIONS));
    }
```

Comment: How are you creating the menu?

Comment: I have added the code block contributing to menus in view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some menu items such as Copy and Paste you have to write yourself as Eclipse does not know how you want to copy your view objects.

The 'Run As' menu item should appear at the `IWorkbenchActionConstants.MB_ADDITIONS` position in the menu, but only if the view item enablement is correct. For 'Run As' the enablement expression is:

```xml
     <enablement>
        <or>
           <and>
              <not>
                 <with
                       variable="org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform">
                    <test
                          args="org.eclipse.debug.core"
                          property="org.eclipse.core.runtime.bundleState"
                          value="ACTIVE">
                    </test>
                 </with>
              </not>
              <adapt
                    type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
              </adapt>
           </and>
           <and>
              <with
                    variable="org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform">
                 <test
                       args="org.eclipse.debug.core"
                       property="org.eclipse.core.runtime.bundleState"
                       value="ACTIVE">
                 </test>
              </with>
              <test
                    property="org.eclipse.debug.core.launchable"
                    value="run">
              </test>
           </and>
        </or>
     </enablement>
```

Which is testing that the `org.eclipse.debug.core` plugin is installed and that the current selection can be adapted to either an `IResource` or a launchable object.

Comment: Thanks greg-449 , I have added the enablement to view tags in plugin.xml but the 'Run As' is still not appearing. I might be doing it wrong :

Comment: <view
            name="SuitA Explorer"
            icon="icons/sample.gif"
            category="SuitACore"
            class="suitacore.views.SuitAExplorer"
            id="suitacore.views.SuitAExplorer"> <enablement></enablement></view>

Comment: No, this is not something you add, what I showed is the enablement Run As uses - so your view must provide objects which adapt to IResource or launchable. If they don't Run As will not appear.

Comment: thanks greg-449 - i modified my view and wizard to create IResources and this is working now.